# Best tool for visualizing functions

Tags: matlab

I am looking for tools which can help me to visualize functions (vector valued). For eg quadratic functions like 1/2x'Ax + q'x where x' is the transpose of x and so on. Which would be the best tool for that. I mean, I just want to give the function and it automatically plots it. I know I can like generate the function values myself and then plot it using plot function and all, but I want something which can do it automatically. Is there anything for that?

Comment: Try [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Comment: Asking for the BEST tool is always considered off-topic on this site, as everybody will have differing opinions.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for [ezplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html)

```
dfig,ezplot(@(x)[x,x]*A*[x;x]+q'*[x;x],[xmin,xmax])
```

should do the trick. Use scalars for `xmin`,`xmax`.

Comment: it didn't work. I used A=[3 2;7 8], xmin=[0;0], xmax=[0;0]. And tried to plot ezplot(@(x)0.5*x*A*x',[xmin,xmax]), but it showed the error

Comment: @user34790: Ok, fixed it.